# Bootstrap: remove blue (or whatever color) outline from a focused element

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I know this question has been asked multiple times, and yet most answers seemed to work for like half of the people. I am in the half for which this has not worked. You can checkout the project at https://jsfiddle.net/erbnzud1/2/.
What I need is for that blue outline to not be shown on focus, so after the button was clicked. As you can see in the CSS, I tried something like this:

```
.btn:focus,.btn:active {
   outline: none !important;
   box-shadow: none !important;
   -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

And many other variations. Let me know if you have any suggestions.

Thanks!

EDIT: This is the current solution that works: https://jsfiddle.net/erbnzud1/3/

Created this css class which I have added to my elements as per the help I got in the answer to my question:

```
.noFocus,.noFocus:focus,.noFocus:active {
   outline: none !important;
   box-shadow: none !important;
   -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is the label outline (the square one). add `label` to your css rule to remove outline:

```
label, .btn:focus,.btn:active {
   outline: none !important;
   box-shadow: none !important;
   -webkit-box-shadow: none !important;
}
```

Comment: @TimA. glad to help